# Garbage Collector Flash

Tags: flash

I´m pretty new to Flash and for the first time I´ve discovered a problem with laggs... since the laggs starts when it throws an null-reference error, I think they belong together.

I´ve tried to use the garbage collector, to set the objects to null and to remove them...nothing worked so far. Help please.

```
                            //Handler for Collisions

                            if (active_ball_array[array_counter] != null)
                            {

                            //Collision:Magma

                            if     (active_ball.hitTestObject(magma))
                            {
                                max_active_balls --;
                                active_ball.parent.removeChild(active_ball);
                                active_ball = null;
                                trace("Ball removed: "+max_active_balls);
                            }

                            //Collision:Vertical
                            if (active_ball.hitTestObject(roof) || active_ball.hitTestObject(p1) || active_ball.hitTestObject(p2) || active_ball.hitTestObject(p3) || active_ball.hitTestObject(p4))
                            {
                                if (animation_array[array_counter] == "crack2")
                                {
                                    max_active_balls --;
                                    active_ball.parent.removeChild(active_ball);
                                    active_ball = null;
                                    trace("Ball removed: "+max_active_balls);
                                }
                                else if(animation_array[array_counter] == "crack1")
                                    {animation_array[array_counter]="crack2";}
                                else
                                    {animation_array[array_counter]="crack1";}

                                mouse_target_hit_array[array_counter] = true;
                                ball_flightY_array[array_counter] *= -1;
                            }

                            //Collision:Horizontal
                            if (active_ball.hitTestObject(wall_L) || active_ball.hitTestObject(wall_R))
                            {
                                if (animation_array[array_counter] == "crack2")
                                {
                                    max_active_balls --;
                                    active_ball.parent.removeChild(active_ball);
                                    active_ball = null;
                                    trace("Ball removed: "+max_active_balls);
                                }
                                else if(animation_array[array_counter] == "crack1")
                                {animation_array[array_counter]="crack2";}
                                else
                                {animation_array[array_counter]="crack1";}

                                mouse_target_hit_array[array_counter] = true;
                                ball_flightX_array[array_counter] *= -1;
                            }
                        }//END active_ball Collision Handler

                        ball_animation(animation_array[array_counter]);
                        firm_distance_array[array_counter] = true;
                        array_counter ++;
                        System.gc();
```

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection in Flash is automatic. You can't really 'use' it. Nullifying un-used objects is a good idea, **if** the program is really finished with them. You have 'active_ball' inside of three separate 'if' statements -- have you nullified it inside of one of these when the program will be trying to reference it later? That's probably what the null reference error is telling you.

Please translate laggs' into English. Do you mean slowdowns?  Also please show the line of code that throws the error.

Comment: Laggs is English i suppose o.O maybe its "gamer slang" I am not sure.  Sorry for that but you got it right. Well i found the answer already. The problem was, that the collision happened like 1000 times on every hit and i fixed that. But to know that the garbage collector is a default helps a lot also, thank you.